# Is is possible to make an XSS in this situation ？

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, xss

I have a jsp file with the following code snippet:

```
<form action=<%= request.getContextPath() %>/query_flight? ...
```

When using [codesecue](http://www.armorize.com/codesecure/) to do static code check, I got an XSS attack warning: 
[image]

But I am confused because `context.getContextPath` is a Java EE standard API. Is it possible to do an XSS attack??

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The tool is wrong. That said, I would use the `<c:url>` JSTL tag to generate the URL. It would take care of the context path, and of URL rewriting if necessary to track sessions.